# Short cut key to open pages

Tags: javascript, html

i have 5 links in my home page ,

linkabc 
linkdef
linkghi
linkjkl
linkmno

when i click the CTRL+b to open the linkabc page ,

When i click the CTRL+e to open the linkdef page like wise,

How to do this functionality with few snnipet ,

Answer (score 1):

No Javascript needed.

```
<a accesskey="b" href="#">linka<u>b</u>c</a>
<a accesskey="e" href="#">linkd<u>e</u>f</a>
```

You can access the first link by pressing `Alt-b`, the second by `Alt-e`.

Answer (score 1):

The vanilla javascript way:

You'll need to bind to the onkeydown event, then retrieve the keycode.
Get keycodes here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx

For modifier keys, you'll need to maintain variables to check if they are depressed.  For instance, if the keycode for control is detected onkeydown, toggle the `var control = true`.  Onkeyup, you'll toggle back: `var control = false`. To trigger the action, you'll do:

```
if (control && e.keycode == 66) { // 66 happens to be "b"
  performAction();
}
```

This is much easier if you're using a library, though, as there are plugins for all major javascript libraries for keybindings, such as this one for jQuery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) has a little Javascript library that lets you bind keyboard shortcuts. Might try looking into that. He has a little demo on that page and it seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the accesskey attribute of the Html Anchor tag as follows but you will press ALT instead of CTRL:-

```
<a accesskey="b" href="linkabc.html">linka<u>b</u>c</a> 
<a accesskey="e" href="linkdef.html">linkd<u>e</u>f</a>
```

I hope this helps you and you can check this url for more information:-

**http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key**

Comment: this one not working       <a href="../more/more.php" accesskey="m">More Action</a>, when i click the ALT+m, nothing happened